# Why react cannot import index.js in firefox?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, firefox

I use chrome in react app. in chrome react app work well. but when open this firefox I cannot see. after I see elements. But its have only `<div id="root"></div>` console tab no errors. Can I do this?

Comment: Please add your codes

Comment: https://github.com/Feruz00/mern-auth-boilerplate

Comment: simple react apps cannot open